# LXC, Port forwarding and iptables

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, lxc

I have a LXC container (`10.0.3.2`) running on a host. A service is running inside the container on port `7000`.

From the host (`10.0.3.1`, `lxcbr0`), I can reach the service:

```
$ telnet 10.0.3.2 7000
Trying 10.0.3.2...
Connected to 10.0.3.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'd love to make the service running inside the container accessible to the outer world. Therefore, I want to forward port `7002` on the host to port `7000` on the container:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7002 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.2:7000
```

Which results in (`iptables -t nat -L`):

```
DNAT   tcp  --  anywhere     anywhere     tcp dpt:afs3-prserver to:10.0.3.2:7000
```

Still, I cannot access the service from the host using the forwarded port:

```
$ telnet 10.0.3.1 7002
Trying 10.0.3.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I feel like I'm missing something stupid here. What things should I check? What's a good strategy to debug these situations?

For completeness, here is how `iptables` are set on the host:

```
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -X

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7002 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.2:7000
```

Comment: Did you check the `INPUT` chain? Maybe the policy is `REJECT` there.

Comment: Policy is `ACCEPT`

Comment: Sorry, i meant the `FORWARD` chain. Also check if IP forwarding is enabled: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

Comment: `ip_forward` is set to `1`

Comment: `FORWARD` policy is also `ACCEPT`

Comment: Next things i would try: Check if any packet makes it to the LXC, e.g with `tcpdump`. Also watch the different counters in your iptables, whenever you try to connect. It usually gives you a hint, where a packet is lost. If packets arrive at LXC then check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` and your telnet configuration. Maybe it's blocking IPs outside your network.

Comment: Added the complete specs for `iptables`.

Comment: `tcpdump` (used on `-i lo`) shows a rejection. No packets reach the LXC, apparently.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7899/discussion-between-roberto-aloi-and-michael-hartl)

Comment: I think this is causing you troubles: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -j MASQUERADE. Why do you need that?

Comment: Might be related to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/475065/iptables-port-forwarding-a-b-a  have you tried accessing port 7002 from another computer as the host? i.e telnet $HOSTIP 7002 (where $HOSTIP is the IP of the machine hosting the LXC contianer, say 192.168.1.15 if you are on a common LAN).

Comment: all I needed was the last line

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have blocked 7002 port on 10.0.3.1 as your default policy is DROP

Try adding it to INPUT rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7002 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I have not found solution yet, but following I note down some observations.

I have a host `${host}` machine (Ubuntu 12.04) and it runs a guest machine via LXC. The guest is on `IP 10.0.3.248` and gateway is `10.0.3.1`. I run a web server in the guest and want to port forward traffic from `${host}:8888` to `10.0.3.248:80`. Following is the relevant iptables entries:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.248:80
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

With the current configuration, I can successfully visit the web server on 10.0.3.248:80 from another physical machine. However, it fails when I try to visit 10.0.3.248:80 from `${host}`. Maybe you can try to visit that service inside LXC from another machine.

My understanding is that, when I visit from `${host}`, the packet go through loopback interface and enters the INPUT chain directly. Although I allow everything on INPUT, there is no service listening at `${host}:8888`. From wireshark, I see a RST is sent received. When I visit from another physical machine, the packet goes into PREROUTING chain and was DNAT-ed as expected.

One related post:

- [iptables redirect local connections to remote system / port](https://serverfault.com/questions/247623/iptables-redirect-local-connections-to-remote-system-port)

Answer (score 1):

Following the tutorial from [lxcware](https://lxdware.com/forwarding-host-ports-to-lxd-instances/) got the job done for me. I think it will be easier for most users to use the `lxc` commands instead. A short synopsis, assuming your container's name is `container1` and you are forwarding from your host `7002` to container's `7000`:

```
$ lxc profile create proxy-80
$ lxc profile device add proxy-80 hostport80 proxy \
 connect="tcp:127.0.0.1:7000" listen="tcp:0.0.0.0:7002"
$ lxc profile add container1 proxy-80
```

Check that it applied correctly to your container:

```
$ lxc config show container1 -e
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a FORWARD rule

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.3.2 --dport 7002 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, my 5 cents from year 2018:

I did install LXC and play around it. My container IP is `10.0.0.10`

I added this rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ens192 --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:22
```

It did not worked. Then I realized, that even FORWARD policy is ACCEPT, there is a rule that blocks all FORWARD's.

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/24          ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       10.0.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   268 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

So I had to inject rule at the top:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Now forward `host:81` -> `10.0.0.10:22` works.

Answer (score -2):

Your container is accessible from LAN via a host bridge interface, and thus connected to the same subnet as the host.

You need to have your router forward those ports to your container.